# Gaussian noise added to image, how secure is it?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Parties A and B know the random noise seed. Assume the seed is perfectly secure. Can the image possibly be recovered by someone who doesn't know the seed, *assuming they have the decryption source code?* So the only thing they need to figure out is the seed. Encryption is:

```
random_seed(42)
noise = 100 * randn(img.shape)  # 10000 variance
img += noise  # img variance before noise = 1
```

One method is to brute force (there are `2**32 - 1` seeds for the RNG in question), then filter out obvious noise (e.g. exclude based on histogram) and manually inspect the rest. But that's fairly time consuming, and intractable if there's multiple seeds to guess. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: If I'm understanding the idea correctly, superficially this seems like an image based implementation of a one-time pad encryption. However, it falls short of the definition due to the key being derived pseudo-randomly from a shorter seed, as for an OTP the key would have to be at least as long as the plaintext. While that doesn't mean recovering the image would be easy, it does mean that it does not have the OTP's guarantee of impossibility to crack. I'd cautiously guess that it is thus at least theoretically possible.

Comment: At the very least, it'll depend on the random number generator, and how predictable the image is (for instance, if it has large areas of constant color, it'll be easy to just average the noise out over a flat area).

Comment: @GordonDavisson _"average the noise out over a flat area"_, with -80dB SNR? I'm afraid that's not remotely true. And unless we're talking very fancy "averaging", it's not true with any substantial noise.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon When you're trying to infer the internal state of the RNG, the output of the RNG is the signal and the original image is the noise, so you need to invert that. If it's not a strong RNG, you're in trouble.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's quite an interesting point; more noise is worse! (when we have the code) -- Still doesn't it suffice to multi-layer it so multiple seeds have to be guessed, and make it enough seeds that no computer can brute check them all?